# Centos 7.1 GUI install fail after driver B140i

Tags: centos, centos7, hpe

Im trying to install Centos 7.1 on a HPE DL160 GEN9 using the smart array controller.

Im following the official manual (*HPE Dynamic Smart Array B140i
RAID Controller User Guide*) after the driver setup via USB the install fails and show a blackscreen only with the mouse on it.

anyone can help me with this

Thanks

Comment: i solve this installing centos 7.0 and driver version 7.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The steps provided below worked for a similar case for DL20 Gen9 server. I think the key item is using the HPE Dynamic Smart Array B140i SATA RAID Controller Driver for Red Hat Enterprise Linux driver provided in step 2.

1) Download CentOS Image and write it on a USB using `dd` (ex. `dd if=/path/to/CentOS.iso of=/dev/sdX status=progress`);

2) Download hpdsa-1.2.10-123.rhel7u3.x86_64.dd.gz file from the following webpage:

- RECOMMENDED * HPE Dynamic Smart Array B140i SATA RAID Controller Driver for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 (64-bit)
  https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=MTX_090fe0d487ed4bd2b07234b37f#tab-history

3) Use `dd` to write the appropriate driver (u0 or u1) on a separate USB drive (ex. `dd if=/path/to/HpDsaExtractedDriver.dd of=/dev/sdY status=progress`);

4) Insert the CentOS USB in the server, boot from it but at the install menu, press <kbd>e</kbd> in case of an UEFI system and on the "linuxefi" line append the following `inst.dd modprobe.blacklist=ahci;`

5) Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> or the keys needed to continue the installation;

6) Insert the usb drive with the driver;

7) Press <kbd>r</kbd> to refresh the drive list and choose the appropriate drive;

8) After it unpacks, continue with the installation as usual.

This support communication also has similar instructions for REHL 7.x that should also work for Centos 7

Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.x - B140i Raid Controller Driver Update disk (dd) Creation
https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=mmr_kc-0135766

-V

Comment: exactly ,for some weird reason this works for me only with centos 7.0 and the driver for 7.0 (hpdsa-1.2.4-140.rhel7u0.x86_64),newest versions fail on the install ,thanks for your answer btw :)

Comment: Can confirm this works on a DL160 gen9 with Centos 7 on 11/13/18. I used the "u4" edition of the driver.

Comment: Can confirm step #4 works for using the Centos DVD/USB to repair a broken Centos 7 system. I hosed my LVM XFS root volume.

Comment: Worked for me on DL160 Gen9 with Centos 7.9.2009 on 6/9/23. I also had to use the "u4" edition of the driver as the "u3" edition didn't work. This solution was a true life saver - almost 5 years after it was posted!